# Flash animation in a Facebook tab. Am I allowed to have a brief wecome animation/Consistent background animation without user interaction

Tags: facebook, policy

Hi I've been called up by a partner of a client I work for on the following Facebook rule

Special provisions for apps on Pages:
a. Apps on Pages must not host media that plays automatically without a user's interaction.

I have several elements I could see breaking this rule.
-When the .swf loads there is a brief animation that brings together the elements of the welcome page
-After these elements are brought together there is a consistent background animation of bubbles floating in the background
-prior to the initial animation we have a loading screen to let the user know the .swf is loading. This includes a pulsing loading image and as well as bubbles similar to the welcome screen.

Can anyone conform whether some or all of these element do or don't break Facebook's rules.

The on in particular that I would have expected there to be a mitigation for is the first one as I have seen many apps that have a simple animation at the start as the elements of the welcome screen are being put in place

Comment: "I have seen many apps that have a simple animation at the start as the elements of the welcome screen are being put in place" - The fact that other people are doing this does not justify it.

Comment: Facebook policy, legal, acceptable use and rules questions are not on topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> "When the .swf loads there is a brief animation... "

Thats enough for me to say that the page is violating the facebook platform policy. 
With regard to `swf` files - as soon as the timeline has started throwing `enterFrame` events, the *media* is playing.  A pre-loading animation is also automatic playback.